# Browserstack's Parallel threads not supporting for Cypress version 12

Tags: cypress, browserstack, parallels

We are looking for your support as we are migrating our Cypress automation suite from cypress version 9.7 to 12.8 and we have following configuration set in browserstack.json. As you can see parallels is set to 25 but whenever we execute the suite it only runs it with 3 threads (not sure from where this number is picked). I also tried sending the parallel count at run time

`“browserstack-cypress run --sync --parallels 25 --env userAgent=desktop”`

```
        "cypress_proj_dir": "./",
        "cypress_config_file": "./cypress.config.js",
        "parallels": 25,
        "npm_dependencies": {
            "@percy/cypress": "^3.1.1",
            "@types/cypress": "^1.1.3",
            "axe-core": "^4.1.4",
            "browserstack-cypress-cli": "^1.20.0",
            "cypress": "^12.3",
            "cypress-axe": "^1.3.0",
            "cypress-failed-log": "^2.9.2",
            "cypress-iframe": "^1.0.1",
            "cypress-localstorage-commands": "^1.7.0",
            "date-and-time": "^1.0.0",
            "gmail-tester": "^1.3.5",
            "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
            "oracledb": "^5.0.0",
            "path": "^0.12.7",
            "qs": "^6.9.4"
        }
```

[image]

Looking forward for your support.

Answer (score 0):

The number of parallels will be equal to the number of devices you have defined in your capabilities.

Please try to add 25 devices to your Browserstack capabilities.

Thanks.